# Privileges page columns are misaligned on mobile

Tags: bug, responsive-design, privileges-page

Misalignment with the [privileges page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

There are 3 sections. The rep count, the name of the privilege, and the description. The description section is not aligned correctly vertically when the name of privilege is too long.

[image]

Comment: Hmm... I'm not seeing that when I resize on desktop, but I do see it on mobile. I'm using a Google Pixel 3a on Chrome ver. 103.0.5060.71

Comment: It's not a table, but it really should be. In addition to the display problems you noted, it's tedious to navigate using a screen reader since you can't move down the columns.